# Is it possible to use a conditional inside where clause in LinQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a simple LinQ query in this way:

```
myList.Where(x=> x.Property.Property2 == 5);
```

However, Property could be null and then I get an error. So I would like to know if there is any way to check if it is null, if not null, do the comparation, if it is null, throw an exception.

Because if not, I have to use a foreach to check each element, in this way:

```
List<MyType> myLstResult = new List<MyType>();
foreach(MyType iterator in myList)
{
    if(iterator.Property == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
    if(iterator.Property.Property2 == 5)
    {
        myLstresult.Add(iterator);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can extend the lambda just like that:

```
myList.Where(x=> 
    {
        if (x.Property == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        return x.Property.Property2 == 5;
    });
```

---

This will of course only work in "normal" linq. Linq-to-sql or -entity query providers will probably not be able to translate that to sql.

Comment: I don't like queries which cause exceptions. I'd certainly prefer a loop then. _"However, we recommend that you avoid calling any method in a query expression that can create a side effect such as modifying the contents of the data source or **throwing an exception**"_ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513730.aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter I agree, but that's what OP asked for.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Waht was the problem with `myList.Where(x=> x.Property?.Property2 == 5);` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir that OP _wanted_ to throw an `ArgumentNullException`, not _avoid_ it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Oh Ok. tnx.

Comment: Thanks, then I will follow the advise of use a loop in this case. Thanks.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía: you might want to have a look at [my updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38198832/284240) which shows a way to use a clean LINQ approach using an extension method.

Answer (score 7):

I would avoid the exception instead.

You could either use the new C#6 null propagation operator:

```
myList.Where(x=> x.Property?.Property2 == 5);
```

or this simple approach:

```
 myList.Where(x=> x.Property != null && x.Property.Property2 == 5);
```

However, if you really want to throw an exception i would use  a plain  loop which is also easier to debug. This is recommended since LINQ queries should not cause side effects or throw exceptions:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513730.aspx

> However, we recommend that you avoid calling any method in a query
>   expression that can create a side effect such as modifying the
>   contents of the data source **or throwing an exception**

So either the `foreach` loop that you've already shown(my favourite) or a `try-catch`:

```
List<MyType> myLstResult = null;
try
{
    myLstResult = myList.Where(x=> x.Property.Property2 == 5).ToList();
}
catch(NullReferenceException nullref)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("MyType.Property must not be null", nullref);
}
// ...
```

[Rene has shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38198827/284240) another approach which i would not recommend to throw an exception. This can't be translated from LINQ providers like `Linq-To-Sql` or `Linq-To-Entities` and violates the aforementioned guidelines.

**Update**: maybe a `ThrowIfArgumentNull` extension method like this comes in handy:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ThrowIfArgumentNull<TSource, TNullable>(this IEnumerable<TSource> enumeration, Func<TSource, TNullable> mightBeNullSelector, string argumentName) 
    where TNullable : class
{
    foreach (TSource item in enumeration)
    {
        if (mightBeNullSelector(item) == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(argumentName);
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

You would use it in this way:

```
List<MyType> myLstresult = myList
    .ThrowIfArgumentNull(x => x.Property, "MyType.Property")
    .Where(x => x.Property.Property2 == 5)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: you could first partition the data into valid/invalid and check for nulls after the loop(s). Depends on the amount of data and if you *need* the exception as soon as a null is spotted.